# Is there a logic error in my Springboot code?

Tags: java, authentication, postman, basic-authentication

I started learning Springboot from an online tutorial and many of the logic/dependencies used for the project has been deprecated so I struggled looking for alternative methods that I can use for basic authentication.

I came across the requestMatchers() method due to antMatchers() being deprecated, I think I somewhat understand the logic but I can't seem to get the authentication to work when posting to the server whenever I use postman. Can someone please assist? This is my SecurityConfig file with the logic

when I start my server then trying to posting to the link

```
package com.workshop.Security.config;

import com.workshop.Security.config.dao.UserDao;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final UserDao userDao;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("**/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
               .anyRequest()
               .authenticated()
               .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter,  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

       return http.build();
    }

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        final DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
}
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
}


@Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
//        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();

    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
       return new UserDetailsService() {
           @Override
           public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                return userDao.findUserByEmail(email);

           }
       };
    }
}
```

This is the error that displays when I try posting to postman (I get a 500 error message)

```
org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PatternParseException: No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element
```

Can someone help me find the error?

I was expecting to authenticate the current user as admin but I can't connect to the server

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, maybe the code line

```
.requestMatchers("**/auth/**")
```

should be changed to

```
.requestMatchers("/auth/**")
```

or something like. That is to say, after "**", there should be nothing.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I have tried your suggestion and now instead of a 500 server error the error message on postman is showing a 403 forbidden. I think now my requestMatchers is correct but for some reason its not posting the authentication now